# Google AppEngine Cron Jobs on custom environment

Tags: google-app-engine, cron, google-app-engine-php

I am having problems when running cron jobs on App Engine.

I have an App Engine Flex custom application running (using php:7.0-apache)

I also have an URL that I can call to run my job, let's say myapp.com/cacheupdate.php, when I point to that URL everything works fine, as the cache is updated correctly.

So I added a cron job:

```
    cron:
    - description: "Update Cache"
    url: /cacheupdate.php
    schedule: every 30 minutes
```

The cron job shows up in the console but always gives an error. So I added a handler for it in my app.yaml file:

```
    handlers:
    - url: /updatecache.php
     script: /cacheupdate.php
```

I have tried a few different ways to specify the source URL, but the problem persists.

I'm assuming the issue here is that I'm using a custom Docker image to build the instances, is there a better way to run cron jobs or have I missed something?

Comment: The cron service is just an automated `GET` request at the specified URL. If the same URL works manually the issue is elsewhere. The usual suspect is authentication: cron doesn't run with a regular user's credentials. What do you see in the app logs?

Comment: Is your handler in the default service? If not you may have to set a `target` option in your cron.yaml file: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml#about

Comment: when i see the failure on the cron job page i don't see anything in the log, the url works even with out me logged into the application (ive removed everything from the file apart from an echo line to test with.)

I assume the cron job just uses the url of the project and then the url entry for the job?

Comment: @RobertBryden have you checked the [firewall settings](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/creating-firewalls#allowing_requests_from_your_services)? You have to open both `10.0.0.1` and `0.1.0.40` so that your Flex service can receive requests from cron.